# Create IPA in Visual Studio without Developer Account

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2015

We need to release our Xamarin.Forms app for our customer as ipa-file, so he can release it in his company enterprise store. So my plan for deployment is this:

- Customer sends me Distribution Certificate etc.
- I create an IPA with these files and send the IPA back

Can i do this within Visual Studio without an apple developer account?
Or do i need to handle it in xcode? (i didn't work with xcode yet).

Answer (score 2):

In order for you to build iOS solutions in Xamarin, you need an Apple Developer Account as this is where your certificates and provisioning profiles are stored.

You can always [import a certificate](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW15) that has been provided by someone else.

Afterwards, you can build your IPA in Visual Studio. You just need to set up a [Build Host](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/introduction_to_xamarin_ios_for_visual_studio/) and use an [Ad-Hoc Distribution](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution/ad-hoc-distribution/) in your case.

It may seem a bit tedious to configure your certificates and signing identities if you havn't done so before, but we've all been there.